# PowerShell multiple statement conditions - compare dates in filenames

Tags: powershell

What I am trying to do is any file name with "D" value that is 4 days or older than "t" value - do something.
For example:
(t = today's day)(d = is typically the same as t, but occasionally it is 4 days or more older)

c:\temp\test_d210115_t210115.txt - won't do anything

c:\temp\test_d210112_t210115.txt - won't do anything

c:\temp\test_d210108_t210115.txt - do something

c:\temp\test_d210111_t210115.txt - do something

```
$DATA_DATE = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-4).ToString("yyMMdd"))
$TODAY_DATE = (get-date).ToString("yyMMdd")
$TXT_FILES = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\*

$DATA = $TXT_FILES.Name -filter "*d$TODAY_DATE*"

if ($data -like "*d$DATA_DATE*") -and ($data -le "*d$DATA_DATE*"){

    Write-Output "$data"
}
```

I would like TRUE everytime. Please help for the life of me I cannot figure this out...
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, dates in the filenames should be compared and if the date listed after `d` is 4 days or more less (older) then the date listed after `t`, you want to do something to that file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp' -Filter '*.txt' | 
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match 'd(\d{6})_t(\d{6})$' } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $dateD = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'yyMMdd', $null)
        $dateT = ([datetime]::ParseExact($matches[2], 'yyMMdd', $null)).AddDays(-4)
        if ($dateD -le $dateT) {
            # do something with this file. For demo, just output the file's FullName
            $_.FullName
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp\test_d210108_t210115.txt
C:\Temp\test_d210111_t210115.txt
```

Regex details:

```
d              Match the character “d” literally
(              Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d          Match a single digit 0..9
      {6}      Exactly 6 times
)             
_t             Match the characters “_t” literally
(              Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   \d          Match a single digit 0..9
      {6}      Exactly 6 times
)             
$              Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

Comment: Seems to work very well until the last day of the month. I noticed that "d210131_t210201" this will get flagged  until "d" value reaches to "d21002..".

Comment: @kurama What was I thinking at first... The conversion to [int] seemed to work, but was flawed as you have commented. I have edited my answer now and use conversions to real DateTime objects

Comment: Thank you @Theo! Looks like this is working perfectly from my test.